# A valid singleton Class ？

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

```
class Singleton
{
 private:
     static Singleton s;
     Singleton(){}
 public:
    static Singleton *getInstance()
    {
        return &s;
    }
};

Singleton Singleton::s;
```

Is this a valid singleton class？

```
class Singleton
{
 private:
     static Singleton *m_instance;
     Singleton(){}
 public:
    static Singleton *getInstance()
    {
        return m_instance;
    }

};
Singleton * Singleton::m_instance = new Singleton;
```

.

```
class Singleton
{
 private:
     static Singleton *m_instance;
     Singleton(){}
 public:
    static Singleton *getInstance()
    {
        if(m_instance == NULL)
        {
            lock();
            if(m_instance == NULL)
                m_instance = new Singleton;
            unlock();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }

};
Singleton * Singleton::m_instance = NULL;
```

The three singleton classes above both are thread safe, but they are both prone to "static initialization order fiasco", am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a valid singleton class？

Now, after the edit the answer is yes, it is valid & it is also thread safe since all non-function-scope static variables are constructed before `main()`, while there is only one active thread.

**C++ Standard n3337 § 3.6.2/1 § 3.6.2/2: Initialization of non-local variables**

> There are two broad classes of named non-local variables: those with
>   static storage duration (3.7.1) and those with thread storage duration
>   (3.7.2). Non-local variables with static storage duration are
>   initialized as a consequence of program initiation. Non-local
>   variables with thread storage duration are initialized as a
>   consequence of thread execution. Within each of these phases of initiation, initialization occurs as follows.
>
> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
>   initialization takes place. Constant initialization is performed:
>
> — if each full-expression (including implicit conversions) that
>   appears in the initializer of a reference with static or thread
>   storage duration is a constant expression (5.19) and the reference is
>   bound to an lvalue designating an object with static storage duration
>   or to a temporary (see 12.2);
>
> — if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized
>   by a constructor call, if the constructor is a constexpr constructor,
>   if all constructor arguments are constant expressions (including
>   conversions), and if, after function invocation substitution (7.1.5),
>   every constructor call and full-expression in the mem-initializers and
>   in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members is a
>   constant expression;
>
> — if an object with static or thread storage duration is not
>   initialized by a constructor call and if every full-expression that
>   appears in its initializer is a constant expression.
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called
>   static initialization; all other initial- ization is dynamic
>   initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any
>   dynamic initialization takes place. (...)

**C++ Standard n3337 § 6.7/4: Declaration statement**

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant
>   initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage
>   duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first
>   entered. An implementation is permitted to perform early
>   initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread
>   storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is
>   permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread
>   storage duration in namespace scope. Otherwise such a variable is
>   initialized the first time control passes through its declaration;
>   such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its
>   initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception,
>   the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next
>   time control enters the declaration. **If control enters the declaration
>   concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent
>   execution shall wait for completion of the initialization*).** (...)

*):

> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of
>   the initializer.

But it is still prone to [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). The common way to write `getInstance` is:

```
Singleton& getInstance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

This way you can avoid this initialization problem.

> Is this a thread-safe singleton class？

In C++11 above code is thread safe. In C++03 you can use

[`pthread_once`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_once.html)

---

Besides this you should also prevent from copying and assignment:

```
Singleton( Singleton const&);      // Don't Implement
void operator=( Singleton const&); // Don't implement
```

Comment: before C++11 object initialization could have been done by multiple threads

Comment: The three singleton classes above both are thread safe, but they are both prone to "static initialization order fiasco", am I right? @lizusek

Comment: they all are thread safe in C++11 (and not in C++03) but prone to static initialization order fiasco

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, it's thread safe. But it's susceptible to [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

If an object tries to access `Singleton` in it's constructor and that object is constructed during program initialization and this code is in another compilation unit than `Singleton`, it may or may not crash because `Singleton::s` may or may not have been initialized yet (because the order of initialization of static objects across compilation units is undefined). Here is an example:

```
// in another compilation unit, far far away
struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        Singleton::getInstance();
    }
};
Foo foo;
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @lizusek, I've added an example.

Comment: And the problems of order of initialization are one of the main reasons to use a singleton in C++.

Answer (score 0):

That's the lazy initialised Singleton, yes. It is thread safe under C++11.

Comment: _'That's the lazy initialised Singleton, yes ...'_ No, it isn't!